# How to make the double quote behave as a dead key except when it is used in combination with itself

Tags: keyboard-layout

When I use a keyboard, I expect the following behaviours (and I rely on these behaviours):

- **Press <kbd>"</kbd>, release <kbd>"</kbd>**: Should remember the key as a dead key
- **Press <kbd>"</kbd>, release <kbd>"</kbd>, press <kbd><space></kbd>, release <kbd><space></kbd>**: Should print `"`
- **Press <kbd>"</kbd>, release <kbd>"</kbd>, press <kbd>"</kbd>, release <kbd>"</kbd>**: Should print `""`

I understand that this behaviour is defined by a keyboard layout, so I did some research.

On keyboard layout "English - US with dead keys", I get the top 2 behaviours that I prefer, but the last behaviour is not fulfilled, and I get the weird character `¨` when I try that.

On keyboard layout "English - US with AltGr dead keys", I only get the last behaviour, but the key doesn't behave dead anymore.

How can I modify the keyboard layout to fulfill the 3 behaviours I expect when I use a keyboard?

Comment: This question would be a lot better with some motivation.

Comment: I believe his motivation is to avoid mismatched double quotes in string literals. Seems a bit overkill to achieve this by modifying the overall keyboard behaviour - this should be handled by the IDE used for whatever purpose it is.

Comment: @Joshua In my country, people grown up with computer lessons on windows, and these dead key behaviors are the default on windows in my country. Its really hard to change a habit you learned 20 years ago when you both use Ubuntu and Windows at the same time. On Windows the keyboard layout with this behavior is called "English - Us - International with dead keys"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After trying differend ways for this problem, I eventually found a solution with [help in chat for this problem](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/conversation/how-to-make-the-double-quote-behave-as-a-dead-key-expect-when-it-is-used-in-combi)

The root cause of the problem is actually caused by the fact that Linux does not have an `dead_apostrophe` and a `dead_quotedbl` by default, so the default "us dead keyboard layout" have either mapped a `dead_acute` or a non dead key mapped to `"`.

This meant this problem is not being fixable by making your own custom keyboard layout, as I was suggested in the chat.

After further research and the just is time learning of new keywords to search, I found [this solution on Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/224053/43400), what helped me solve the problem.

I followed the following steps listed in that answer:

1. `sudo apt install uim`
2. `echo 'export GTK_IM_MODULE="uim"' >> ~/.profile`
3. `echo 'export QT_IM_MODULE="uim"' >> ~/.profile`
4. `curl 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/guiambros/b773ee85746e06454596/raw/0ea6d7f7cf9a6ff38b4cafde24dd43852e46d5e3/.XCompose' > ~/.XCompose`
5. Configure my keyboard layout to "English (US - intl with dead keys)"
6. Rebooted Ubuntu (according to the comments, logging out and in is enough)

After these steps, I managed to fulfill the following expectations I had about my keyboard:

> - **Press <kbd>"</kbd>, release <kbd>"</kbd>**: Should remember the key as a dead key
> - **Press <kbd>"</kbd>, release <kbd>"</kbd>, press <kbd><space></kbd>, release <kbd><space></kbd>**: Should
>     print `"`
> - **Press <kbd>"</kbd>, release <kbd>"</kbd>, press <kbd>"</kbd>, release <kbd>"</kbd>**: Should print `""`

Comment: To log out of the session and log back in should be enough to let changes to the user configuration take effect. No need to reboot.