# Us international layout : Double hit on ' dead key to get ' instead of ´

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

[Ubuntu Focal Fossa - 20.4]

So I just discovered the `Us international layout with dead keys` and I think it's great
but there's a behaviour that is quite annoying. In order to get to `'` I have to hit `Space + '` because if I hit `'` twice I end up with the most unuseful (when by itself) `´` character.

Can it be changed to get a good old `'` instead ?

Now that I know the names, I want to replace `dead_acute` by `apostrophe` when hitting the apostrophe key twice.

I should note I am not interested in the Alt+Gr variant of the Us international layout. I'd rather use the compose key  instead as I used to as I find to be more convenient.

I am aware of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077736/how-to-make-the-double-quote-behave-as-a-dead-key-except-when-it-is-used-in-comb) and this [one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220510/insert-both-characters-if-a-dead-key-combination-is-not-recognized-e-g-a-%E2%86%92-%C3%A1/224053#224053) but none of those solutions fit the simple remapping I'd like to have. And not tech-savy enough to be able to adapt them to my needs. I know the basics of terminal navigation, a little bash, and how to edit files in vim.

Comment: please [edit] your question with details of your ubuntu version/flavour

Comment: Good question, but I do not think it can be changed easily. I have gotten fully in the habit of hitting the space key, though.

Comment: Well, **'** followed by **<space>** or **RightAlt + '** are two ways to accomplish it. Maybe get used to any of those ways.

Comment: @vanadium I don't think I can get used to hitting space as it need to happen often in english and it is not really intuitive. I am sure I would get used to it but I am not sure I want to :).
@GunnarHjalmarsson I did not know about `RightAlt`, I could get used to that better thanks
Of course nothing would beat the easiness of double hitting the key.